# Use integration by parts $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x \cdot \ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, limits

$$I=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x \cdot \ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

Clearly $$-2I=\int^{\infty}_{0} \ln x \cdot \frac{-2x }{(1+x^2)^2} dx$$

My attempt :

$$-2I=\left[ \ln x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 - \int^{\infty}_{0} \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{x} dx$$

$$-2I=\left[ \ln x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 - \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}  dx$$

$$-2I=\left[ \ln x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 - \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1+x^2-x^2}{x(1+x^2)}  dx$$

$$-2I=\left[ \ln x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 - \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{2x}{1+x^2} dx$$

$$-2I=\left[ \ln x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 -\left[ \ln x -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln(1+x^2) \right]^\infty_0 $$

$$-2I=\left[  \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\right]^\infty_0 -\left[\ln \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right) \right]^\infty_0 $$

How can I evaluate the last limits ?

Comment: The integral has a finite value, but splitting it the way you have done fails because $\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}$ is $\infty$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @almagest Any reasons why my method fails ? thank you

Comment: You have split the integral into (the difference of) two parts each of which has value $\infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put $x=\dfrac1y$

$$I=\int_\infty^0\dfrac{y^4\cdot -\ln(y)}{y(y^2+1)^2}\cdot-\dfrac{dy}{y^2}=\int_\infty^0\dfrac{y\ln y}{(1+y^2)^2}dy=-\int_0^\infty\dfrac{y\ln y}{(1+y^2)^2}dy=-I$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $x=\tan y$

$$\implies2J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\cdot\ln(\tan y)dy$$

Now use $$I=\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$
$$\implies2I=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b\left(f(x)+f(a+b-x)\right)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} &=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\equiv\ J}}\ +\
\int_{1}^{\infty}{x\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}
The second integral in the RHS $\underline{\mbox{is equal to}}$ $\ds{-J}$ after the sub$\ldots$ $\ds{x \to {1 \over x}}$ such that
$\fbox{$\quad\ds{\color{#f00}{I} = J + \pars{-J} = \color{#f00}{0}}\quad$}$.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use $0$ to $1$ then $1$ to $\infty$ ? Can we use $0$ to $a$ then $a$ to $\infty$ for any $a$ ? Thank you

Comment: @AngeloMark With $a > 0$, it's correct the splitting $\left(0,a\right)$ and $\left(a,\infty\right)$. However, $\color{#f00}{a = 1}$ is quite convenient because it shows right away the cancellation of both integrals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A faster approach:
$$ J(a,b)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^b}{a^2+x^2}\,dx = a^{b-1} \frac{\pi}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi b}{2}\right)}\qquad (a>0,b\in(-1,1))\tag{1}$$
is a consequence of the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function and Euler's beta function properties.
By considering:
$$ \lim_{b\to 1^-}\lim_{a\to 1^-}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial a \partial b} \tag{2}$$
we recover the value of our integral by differentiation under the integral sign. That gives:

> $$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx = \lim_{b\to 1^-} -\frac{\pi}{8}\cdot \frac{2+\pi(b-1)\tan\left(\frac{\pi b}{2}\right)}{ \cos\left(\frac{\pi b}{2}\right)}=\color{red}{0}\tag{3}$$

that also follows from a symmetry argument:

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx +\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{x}\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}0\,dx = \color{red}{0}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: many thanks for your answer sir :) But my integration knowledge is not sufficient to understand the answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @AngeloMark: leave $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ behind: I think $(4)$ is a straighforward argument, don't you think? Break the integration range in two pieces and apply the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ on the second piece: everything cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

> Integration by parts works fine provided one writes the integral $I$ as
>
> $$I=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{\epsilon}^L\frac{x\log(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$

Then, proceeding with integration by parts, we find

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac14\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\lim_{L\to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{2x^2\log(x)}{1+x^2}-\log(1+x^2)\right)\right|_{\epsilon}^L\\\\
&=\frac14\lim_{L\to \infty}\left(\frac{2L^2\log(L)}{1+L^2}-\log(1+L^2)\right)\\\\
&-\frac14\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\frac{2\epsilon^2\log(\epsilon)}{1+\epsilon^2}-\log(1+\epsilon^2)\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, since $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\epsilon^2 \log(\epsilon)=0$, the contribution from the evaluation of the lower limit vanishes.

To evaluate the contribution from the upper limit, we write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2L^2\log(L)}{1+L^2}-\log(1+L^2)&=\frac{2L^2\log(L)}{1+L^2}-2\log(L)-\log(1+1/L^2)\\\\
&=-2\frac{\log(L)}{1+L^2}-\log(1+1/L^2)
\end{align}$$

which clearly approaches zero as $L\to \infty$.

And that is that!